# How to change bulk post status

Tags: posts, wp-query

I have about 2300+ post in my blog is it possible to change status from publish to draft at a time?

```
add_action('publish_post', 'check_publish_post', 10, 2);

function check_publish_post ($post_id, $post) {

    $query = array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
    );
    wp_update_post( $query, true );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to loop all publish posts and change their post status to draft.

```
add_action('admin_init','wpse_244394');

function wpse_244394(){
    $args = array('post_type'=> 'post',
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page'=>-1
    );
    $published_posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach($published_posts as $post_to_draft){
       $query = array(
        'ID' => $post_to_draft->ID,
        'post_status' => 'draft',
       );
       wp_update_post( $query, true );  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Here's a way with WP-CLI:**

We can list the *published* posts (ids) with:

```
wp post list --post_status=publish --post_type=post --format=ids
```

We can update a post with ID as 123 to *draft* status with:

```
wp post update 123 --post_status=draft
```

We can combine these two commands, to bulk change all *published* posts to *draft*, with:

```
wp post list --post-status=publish --post_type=post --format=ids \
| xargs -d ' ' -I % wp post update % --post_status=draft
```

where we set the `xargs` *delimiter* to `' '` to match the `ids` format.

Alternatively we can use:

```
for post_id in $(wp post list --post_status=publish --post_type=post --format=ids); \ 
do wp post update $post_id --post_status=draft; done;
```

Note: Remember to backup before testing.

Answer (score 1):

Hers is you code with explanatory comments:

```
<?php

/**
 * Unpublish all posts (set post_status to draft).
 *
 * This code is run only once in a lifetime. 
 */
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_244394' );
function wpse_244394(){

    /**
     * Make sure this code is run ever once.
     */
    if ( get_option( 'wpse_244394' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    update_option( 'wpse_244394', 1 );


    /**
     * Get pubkushed posts.
     */
    $posts = get_posts( [
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'numberposts' => -1,
    ] );

    /**
     * Unpublish.
     */
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $post['post_status'] = 'draft';
        wp_update_post( $post );
    }
}
```

Comment: is your code change the post status from publish to draft? But I see it for draft to publish

Comment: I need from publish to draft

Comment: Code updated...

Comment: undefined function `set_option()`

Comment: It should be `update_option`

Comment: is the function execute automatically?

Comment: Yes, it runs once, you don't want it to run with every single request

Answer (score 1):

you can change the all post status directly from database.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'draft' WHERE post_status = 'publish';
```

Comment: Why do you assume the table is called `wp_posts`?

Comment: I guess that the best option for a very large website (600.000+ posts...) is really to use a direct MySQL query... because I don't want to change _all_ posts, just those that are, say, over three years old... and that's just adding a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This approach is not recommended, some plugins may want to do something when status change and with this method that code would be completely skipped.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @Nabil Kadimi don't work (for me). I got a 500 error.
Here my updated code.

**No guarantee! Be sure to create SQL Backup!**

```
/**
 * Unpublish all posts (set post_status to draft).
 *
 * This code is run only once in a lifetime. 
 */
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_244394' );
function wpse_244394(){

    /**
     * Make sure this code is run ever once.
     */
    if ( get_option( 'wpse_244394' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    update_option( 'wpse_244394', 1 );


    /**
     * Get published posts.
     */

     $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );


    /**
     * Unpublish.
     */
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
      $my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $post->ID,
      'post_status'    => 'draft',
    );

    // Update the post into the database
      wp_update_post( $my_post );

    }

}
```